# Is there a cat alternative that supports unbuffered output?

Tags: linux, software-rec

I'm looking for a program to copy stdin to stdout while showing control characters (like `cat -v`) and without waiting for an EOF (the input is from a `tail -f`). I have GNU|Linux; the `cat` that's installed ignores the `-u` flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU `cat` ignores `-u` because its output is **always unbuffered**. So, when you ask for unbuffered output with `-u`, you get it (but you also get it even when you don't ask for it).

GNU `tail` has the same, always-unbuffered behaviour.

To prove this, in one shell I did:

```
while :; do echo -ne "hello\t"; sleep 1;done > testtail
```

which appends the word 'hello' followed by a tab, every second (with no newlines)

In another shell I did (`cat -T` is similar to `cat -v` -- it shows tabs as ^I):

```
tail -f testtail | cat -T
```

which gives me:

```
hello^Ihello^Ihello^Ihello^I ...
```

updated every second.

Comment: Thank you for this! Just to check, is there a primary source by which we could confirm this? I looked at the man page for `cat` on my system (Ubuntu) but didn't see anything.

Comment: For reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cat-invocation.html#cat-invocation - I do see indirect evidence from `stdbuf`s man pages: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html - "uses the ISO C FILE streams for input/output (note the programs dd and cat don’t do that)"

Answer (score 4):

BSD `cat`'s `-u` option disabled output buffering. From `man cat`:

```
-u      Disable output buffering.
```

Comment: According to the man page on this machine, `-u` is ignored.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Chances are, you're noy using *BSD* `cat`

Comment: Nope, it's GNU `cat` (or whichever version is standard on Ubuntu). I guess I should've been more specific…